# Converting string to number - parseInt() vs Number();

Tags: javascript, numbers, parseint

Why in this situation when i want to convert string to number parseInt() works but Number() not?

```
parseInt(this.element.style.left) << it works
Number(this.element.style.left) << it doesn't, there is NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

With [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

In contrast, `Number` tries to parse the *entire argument* as a number.

With `style.left` ending in `px`, for example, `parseInt('12px')` works because the `px` can just be ignored by the `parseInt`. But `Number('12px')` doesn't work because *all the characters* of the `'12px'` cannot be interpreted as a number.

`parseInt` skips invalid characters (and stops parsing there), evaluating to what's been parsed so far.

`Number` *fails to parse at all* when there are any invalid characters anywhere.